# Strange behaviour in the AutoSuggestBox's suggestions list in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, hover, uwp-xaml, mousehover

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour with the AutoSuggestBox in UWP platform, especially regarding its suggestion list elements.

I want to customize those elements with an hover effect that makes a Button appear when the pointer enters the item template… and I would like also to stretch the item's content through all the available template width.

This is the code for the AutoSuggestBox (sorry for some non-english property name, but I think it isn't important):

```
        <AutoSuggestBox MinWidth="300" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestoRicerca, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ListaRicerca, Mode=OneWay}"  QueryIcon="Find">
            <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:Colore">
                    <Grid PointerExited="{x:Bind OnExitPointer}" PointerEntered="{x:Bind OnEnterPointer}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30" Margin="0,5,15,5" Fill="{x:Bind ColorBrush, Mode=OneWay}" Stroke="LightGray" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Nome, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ColorAsString, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="LightGray" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Click here" Visibility="{x:Bind IsHovered, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="{x:Bind DisplayDetail}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
        </AutoSuggestBox>
```

The OnEnterPointer and OnExitPointer functions, placed in the main Grid of the ItemTemplate, should make the Button appear always when the pointer is into the Grid area… but this doesn't happen!

Actually, the OnEnterPointer fires ONLY when the pointer is over the Grid's children!

This is shown here in those photos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How could I make the hover effect firing in the entire Grid's area?

THe other thing is about stretching the list item's content, as I said before and as you can see in the pictures… in a normal ListView I know how to do it (place a custom Style in ListView.ItemPresenterStyle with the properly Setter), but here it doesn't work somehow, maybe because it isn't a ListViewItem the standard item in that suggestion list…

If you have any idea about this question also, I would like to know it.

I thank you for your attention and your patience.

Best regards

Comment: The default template says it is a ListView in [popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185404.aspx). So you have changed ItemContainerStyle and it does not work for you?  I haven't tested by building a new project,but I have a guess, will he first question works if you put the event in the ListView?

Comment: When testing I find that I cannot know what you've done when mouse hover. But any way, your event is defined in your item's grid, so please let others know whether you've tried to define it from the whole listview part.